# swing application exe can get java at runtime

Tags: java

I have done project in swing and i need to install this project on my client  machine.is there any technique through which it takes java environment at the time of installation by itself.

Comment: You can bundle a Java version with your app, and then unload everything at once.  Other than this, you would have to use whatever Java version is already installed on the target machine.

Comment: suppose java is not already and my app  automatically download java by itself

Comment: That would be a lot of work.  Typically you would use some other installer technology to do this.  It would download Java and also deploy your app somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Tim sir...but if you have any suggestion regarding this.You can tell me.

Comment: You need to poke around and see what is available.  I have never personally done this before.

Comment: Starting java 9, you can deliver your project, any dependencies with jre as an executable. No need  to install java. Have a look https://steveperkins.com/using-java-9-modularization-to-ship-zero-dependency-native-apps/

Comment: @HemantPatel nice read, thanx!